# How can I change the slot CSS of FormControlLabel?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

mui5

```
"@mui/material": "^5.8.6",
```

I want to have light font weight for label.

[image]

I tried this but i still get bold:

```
<FormControlLabel
  sx={{ label: { fontWeight: "light" } }}
  value="range"
  control={<Radio />}
  label="DateTime Range"
/>
```

[image]

But when I tried using css class it works.

```
<FormControlLabel
  sx={{ '& .MuiFormControlLabel-label': { fontWeight: "light" } }}
  value="range"
  control={<Radio />}
  label="DateTime Range"
/>
```

Comment: Please don't tag your titles. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admittedly, this could be made a bit more clear in the MUI docs.

> You can override the style of the component using one of these
> customization options:
>
> - With a [global class name](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/interoperability/#global-css).
> - With a rule name as part of the component's
>   [`styleOverrides` property](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/#theme-style-overrides) in a custom theme.

The first column in the [CSS table](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/form-control-label/#css) is the "Rule Name" for customizing the component using the [Theme style overrides](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/#theme-style-overrides) at the theme level. *(These generally align with the [slot](https://mui.com/base-ui/getting-started/usage/#slots) names, but should not be confused for them.)* For example:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiFormControlLabel: {
      styleOverrides: {
        label: {
          color: "red"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The second column lists the "Global class name" that can be used to style a component at the component [implementation] level via `sx`/`styled`. For example:

```
<FormControlLabel
  sx={{
    "& .MuiFormControlLabel-label": {
      color: "green"
    }
  }}
  value="range"
  control={<Radio />}
  label="DateTime Range"
/>
```

***or***

```
const StyledFormControlLabel = styled(FormControlLabel)`
  .MuiFormControlLabel-label {
    color: blue;
  }
`;

...


<StyledFormControlLabel
  value="range"
  control={<Radio />}
  label="DateTime Range"
/>
```

Working CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/theme-style-overrides-example-256pzg?file=/demo.tsx

### Aside

The value `light` is not a valid **named** [`font-weight` value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight#values) *(valid named values are `normal`, `bold`, `lighter`, and `bolder`)*, but `sx` will [translate](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/#typography) `light` for you to it's [relative font weight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight#common_weight_name_mapping) (`theme.typography.fontWeightLight`), whereas `styled` and [`createTheme()`](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/#createtheme-options-args-theme) will not do it for you automatically.

> The `fontFamily`, `fontSize`, `fontStyle`, `fontWeight` properties map their
> value to the `theme.typography` value:
>
> ```
> <Box sx={{ fontWeight: 'light' }} /> 
> // equivalent to fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightLight
> ```